# firebase rules based on claims: how to refer to some parent level?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

When defining rules in firebase, is it possible to refer to the higher levels in the hierarchy, like so:

```
"enterprises": {
  "$enterprise_id": {
    "meetings": {
      "$meeting_id": {
        ".read": "$meeting_id === auth.meeting_id && $enterprise_id == auth.enterprise_id",
          "users": {
            "$user_id": {
              ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid && $meeting_id === auth.meeting_id && $enterprise_id === auth.enterprise_id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Which would mean that in order to read the "$meeting_id" node, the user must have a token with both claims of matching meeting_id and enterprise_id.

It does not seem to work, actually, but what would be the way to achieve this ?

Maybe something like: 
`"data.parent().parent().val() === auth.enterprise_id"` ?

Comment: When working with custom tokens i think you have to do `auth.token.meeting_id` instead of `auth.meeting_id`. (see [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-custom) ). Also for debugging I suggest you take it one step at a time, first making sure all you rules work seperately (does meeting_id work yes/no? Does enterprise_id work yes/no?)

Comment: @AndréKool:  actually it seems it is `auth.claims.meeting_id`

Answer (score 0):

After some groping in firebase rule simulator, I figured a few things:

1)  the way to refer to claims of the token is by `auth.claims.meeting_id`

2) the ids within my claims were large integers, that does not work, I converted them to strings.

```
"claims": {
    "meeting_id": "5150900591001600",
    "enterprise_id": "5719825666015232"
  }
```

After that, the rule that refers to higher level ids, like this

`".read": "$meeting_id === auth.claims.meeting_id && $enterprise_id === auth.claims.enterprise_id"`

works fine.

The most important recommandation if you experience similar issues is to use the rule simulator, paste-in your token content, and try 'one step at a time', like @andréKool says.